# Is making money by points based rewards halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalum u Alikum!

I am a student who uses Microsoft Bing for surfing the internet. So its reward program gives me points for each search I make. Doing so I gained enough points to buy a gift card for a game. I redeemed that gift card and sold it to one of my friend. I wanted to ask if the money I earned is halal as it is not earned by doing some hard work or special effort. It merged into my routine and now I am earning some money from it.

So is this way of earning halal?

Comment: I don't know about the Islamic view, so I can only offer my private view: 1. Those points are a kind of money or credit, a doubtful one. 2. The way you get them is doubtful, some kind of trading stamp, but you don't buy anything at Bing. What is their profit in the deal? Sure not charity. 3. You sell what they give you. Is it not halal to sell what someone gives you? All in all, in my personal view, it should be halal, but I won't make a habit out of it. Firstly, because Bing could stop this at any time, and if you relay on the income ... it is like a drug.